# QPushButton brief delay when clicked event connect to disable itself

Tags: python, qt, pyside6

I've observed this rather annoying behavior several times (at least on Windows 10), and I just can't figure out a workaround.

I have come up with a very simple test case:

[image: Derp.ui]

```
def pba():
    mainWindow.pushButtonA.setEnabled(False)
    mainWindow.pushButtonB.setEnabled(True)

def pbb():
    mainWindow.pushButtonB.setEnabled(False)
    mainWindow.pushButtonA.setEnabled(True)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
loader = QUiLoader()
mainWindow = loader.load("Derp.ui", None)

mainWindow.pushButtonA.clicked.connect(pba)
mainWindow.pushButtonB.clicked.connect(pbb)

mainWindow.show()
app.exec()
```

It can be readily seen that there is a brief delay before the pushbutton's clicked signal's connected function can disable the clicked button. Also, there is no such delay if the connected function is configured to disable the other button.

I understand that the function connected to the clicked signal is blocking the GUI loop, but in this case the connected functions are extremely brief and short in duration. (Anyway, starting a new thread to execute `setEnabled(False)` changes nothing.)

If my eyes are not misleading me, it seems that the disabled change is placed in a queue, and before it can be visually displayed the pushbutton first has to visually change states in response to its clicked signal. But I'm not super clear on exactly what is happening behind the scenes when I click a QPushButton.

So, how exactly can I get around this behavior? I simply want the button to be disabled immediately upon being clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is exactly the expected behavior, and is not caused by the blocking of the GUI: on the contrary, it's exactly done to prevent what would happen in case the GUI becomes blocked when the signal is emitted.

A `clicked` signal is emitted when the mouse button is released (specifically, when released *inside* the button area), meaning that the button has become *unpressed*, which automatically triggers an *immediate* repainting that will reflect that state: show the button as unpressed.

That is important in the logic of events, and that's exactly to prevent the blocking of the GUI: the repainting *must* happen before emitting the signal, so that the button is properly displaying the current state; by default, signals are *directly* connected when transmitter and receiver belong to the same thread, meaning that the control is *not* returned until the connected function is completed: so, with this approach, the button will properly show its new (unpressed) state, even if the signal is connected to something that would potentially block the event loop.

The sequence is:

1. mouse button release event: if the button is not the left one, the event is ignored;
2. if the mouse button is the left one, the button widget becomes unpressed: [`isDown()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#down-prop) would return `False`;
3. **immediately repaint** the button as *unpressed*, using [`repaint()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#repaint) instead of [`update()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#update) (which would *schedule* a repaint by queuing a `Paint` event), in order to properly display the new state;
4. `paintEvent()` is called, which will *init* a QStyleOptionButton using various information about the button (including its `isDown()` state) and use the current style to paint the button with that;
5. emit the [`released`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#released) signal;
6. *if* the mouse is within the button area, finally emit the `clicked` signal;

Note that, while [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75559528/2001654) may be fine for your case, it's not completely valid or acceptable, at least for the following reasons:

- you are not checking the mouse button, so that will make the button emit the signal when using *any* mouse button;
- you are not checking if the mouse is within the button area, so you will emit the signal even if the user has *left* the button;
- the underlying style may use animations that will still queue the painting even if the button is already in disabled state;
- a disabled widget does not accept user events, and, by default, a *not accepted* event will be handled by its parent (until *any* of the parents in the tree accepts it); the default implementation of an *enabled* QAbstractButton, instead, automatically accepts the event if it is clicked with the left mouse button; *if* the button is disabled in `mousePressEvent()` and you call the base implementation *after* that, the event will become *not accepted*, meaning that, potentially, any parent above it would receive the event and eventually handle it;
- buttons can also be clicked by pressing the space bar when they have focus;

Also note that disabling a button automatically sets it as *unpressed* (automatically emitting the `released` signal).

A proper and more comprehensive implementation would look like the following:

```py
class QDisablingPushButton(QPushButton):
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if (
            event.button() == Qt.LeftButton
            and self.rect().contains(event.pos())
        ):
            self.setEnabled(False) # release is implicit
            self.repaint()
            self.clicked.emit()
        else:
            super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if (
            event.key() in (Qt.Key_Select, Qt.Key_Space)
            and not event.isAutoRepeat()
            and self.isDown()
        ):
            self.setEnabled(False)
            self.repaint()
            self.clicked.emit()
        else:
            super().keyReleaseEvent(event)
```

Finally, there's a catch.
Emitting the `clicked` signal on your own prevents any [QButtonGroup](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbuttongroup.html) to properly emit the related `idClicked` and `buttonClicked` signals.

If you need to use button groups, you should consider a slightly different implementation:

```py
class Button(QPushButton):
    def disableAndClick(self):
        self.setEnabled(False) # release signal is implicit
        self.repaint()
        self.clicked.emit()
        group = self.group()
        if group:
            try: # for Qt < 5.15
                group.idClicked.emit(group.id(self))
            except AttributeError:
                group.buttonClicked[int].emit(group.id(self))
                # to connect to this signal, you must use:
                # group.buttonClicked[int].connect(function)
            group.buttonClicked.emit(self)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if (
            event.button() == Qt.LeftButton
            and self.rect().contains(event.pos())
        ):
            self.disableAndClick()
        else:
            super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if (
            event.key() in (Qt.Key_Select, Qt.Key_Space)
            and not event.isAutoRepeat()
            and self.isDown()
        ):
            self.disableAndClick()
        else:
            super().keyReleaseEvent(event)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the detail. This is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the question caused me to think this through, and I came up with a solution.

Simple: subclass `QPushButton` and override `mouseReleasedEvent`:

```
class QDisablingPushButton(QtWidgets.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.setEnabled(False)
        QPushButton.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
        self.clicked.emit()
```

Note that this overrides whatever emits the clicked signal, and calling `QPushButton.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)` still doesn't emit it. So you'll probably also want `self.clicked.emit()`